# Display Disk Image Size and Swap Allotment from Docker Command Line

Tags: docker

I would like to know what docker command can be used to display the Swap and Disk Image Size allotment from the command line.

I already tried `docker system info` and `docker system df`, but none display the Disk Image Size and Swap allotments.

Ideally, what I want to be able to see is the following:

[Docker Desktop Resource Allotment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx5OD.png)

`docker system info` gives me the first 2 lines, but I could not find a command that gives me the last 2 lines.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?
docker ps -s

Two different columns relate to size.
size: the amount of data (on disk) that is used for the writable layer of each container.
virtual size: the amount of data used for the read-only image data used by the container plus the container’s writable layer size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work for me since it doesn't tell the total allotment of the disk dedicated to docker. Since everyone in the company I work use Mac I found a way that I don't like too much of knowing how much is the total allotted disk space:

`ls -l ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw | cut -d' ' -f8`

This only works for Mac and I am still trying to find a more general solution. Thanks for the reply anyway :)